# How can I connect uitextview with GCPlaceholderTextView on storyboard?

Tags: ios, uitextview, placeholder

I want to use [`GCPlaceholderTextView`](https://github.com/gcamp/GCPlaceholderTextView)
.

When I make `IBOutlet` `UIPlaceHolderTextView` model, I can't connect `uitextview` on storyboard. I have an error -

```
[UITextView setPlaceholder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.
```

How can I connect `uitextview` with `GCPlaceholderTextView`? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redeclare the class of your `UITextView` in your Storyboard and put `GCPlaceholderTextView`.

Otherwise the object initialized is a `UITextView` and not a `GCPlaceholderTextView` like you want. So it doesn't have the method `setPlaceholder:`

Like this :

[image: Change class of UITextView]